# openSUSE 12 fails to start after installing ESET NOD32 

Tags: linux, anti-virus, opensuse

I am using openSUSE 12 (64-bit). I installed ESET NOD32 Antivirus.

After installing NOD32, it required a restart. After restarting, the system stays in a loading status, and I get following error message:

```
Failed to execute 'etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/ifup-sysctl''/etc
hotplug 'No such file or drectory'
[3301215][drm:intel-dsm-platform-mux-info]* 
MUX INFO call failed

trying manual resume from /dev/diskby-id/ata-WDC-WD7500BPUT-24
```

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this issue?